# php array performance when adding elements one by one vs when adding all of the data at once

Tags: php, arrays, performance, associative-array

for the sake of simplicity i will put a simple example, i have an `$array` and few key and values that i wanna add to this array.. what is better primarily from performance perspective:

1. to add all of those key values in one statement to the array. or
2. it won't harm to just do them one by one.

1

```
$array = [
    $key1 => $value1, 
    $key2 => $value2
];
```

OR

```
$array[$key1] = $value1;
$array[$key2] = $value2;
```

Comment: If you have a handful of keys/values, it will make _absolutely no difference_. If you are adding _tens or hundreds of thousands of members_, there may be a minute difference (in the order of milliseconds), but I wouldn't know which way without benchmarking or digging into the internals. In either case, simply add them in the manner that keeps your code easy to maintain. By far the more limiting performance factor with PHP arrays is memory usage, which is unrelated to how you build your arrays.

Comment: Having run a test case on 100K member arrays, it turns out that _there is actually a significant difference_ for large datasets. Please see my answer for the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a handful of keys/values, it will make *absolutely no difference*. If you deal in arrays with 100K+ members, it does actually make a difference. Let's build some data first:

```
$r = [];
for($i = 1; $i <= 100000; $i++) {
    $r[] = $i; // for numerically indexed array
    // $r["k_{$i}"] = $i; // for associative array
    // array_push($r, $i); // with function call
}
```

This generates an array with `100000` members, one-by-one. When added with a numeric (auto)index, this loop takes `~0.0025` sec on my laptop, memory usage at ~6.8MB. If I use `array_push`, it takes `~0.0065 sec` with the function overhead. When `$i` is added with a named key, it takes `~0.015` sec, memory usage at ~12.8MB. Then, named keys are slower to define.

*But would it make a difference if you shaved 0.015 sec to 0.012 sec?* Or with ^10 volume, 0.15 sec to 0.12 sec, or even 0.075 sec? Not really. It would only really start becoming noticeable if you had 1M+ members. **What you actually do with that volume of data** will take much longer, and should be the primary focus of your optimization efforts.

---

**Update:** I prepared three files, one with the 100K integers from above in one set; another with 100K integers separately defined; and serialized as JSON. I loaded them and logged the time. It turns out that *there is a difference*, where the definition "in one set" is 50% faster and more memory-efficient. Further, if the data is deserialized from JSON, it is *3x faster* than including a "native array".

- "In One Set": `0.075 sec`, `9.9MB`
- "As Separate": `0.150 sec`, `15.8MB`
- "From JSON":  `0.025 sec`, `9.9MB`
- "From MySQL": `0.110 sec`, `13.8MB`*

Then: If you define large arrays in native PHP format, define them in one go, rather than bit-by-bit. If you load bulk array data from a file, `json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'), true)` loading JSON is significantly faster than `include 'data.php';` with a native PHP array definition. Your mileage may vary with more complex data structures, however I wouldn't expect the basic performance pattern to change. For reference: [Source data at BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/cmswares/stack_overflow/src/master/sample_data/100k_ints/).

• *A curious observation: Generating the data from a scratch, in our loop above, was actually much faster than loading/parsing it from a file with a ready-made array!*

• *MySQL: Key-value pairs were fetched from a two-column table with PDO into an array matching the sample data with `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE|PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)` .*

---

**Best practice:** When defining your data, if it's something you need to work with, rather than "crude export/import" data not read or manually edited: Construct your arrays in a manner that *makes your code easy to maintain*. I personally find it "cleaner" to keep simple arrays "contained":

```
$data = [
    'length' => 100,
    'width' => 200,
    'foobar' => 'possibly'
];
```

Sometimes your array needs to "refer to itself" and the "bit-by-bit" format is necessary:

```
$data['length'] = 100;
$data['width'] = 200;
$data['square'] = $data['length'] * $data['width'];
```

If you build multidimensional arrays, I find it "cleaner" to separate each "root" dataset:

```
$data = [];
$data['shapes'] = ['square', 'triangle', 'octagon'];
$data['sizes'] = [100, 200, 300, 400];
$data['colors'] = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
```

On a final note, *by far the more limiting performance factor* with PHP arrays is *memory usage* (see: [array hashtable internals](https://www.npopov.com/2014/12/22/PHPs-new-hashtable-implementation.html)), which is unrelated to how you build your arrays. If you have massive datasets in arrays, make sure you don't keep unnecessary modified copies of them floating around beyond their scope of relevance. Otherwise your memory usage will rocket.

---

• *Tested on Win10 / PHP 8.1.1 / MariaDB 10.3.11 @ Thinkpad L380.*

Comment: Updated: Added performance notes for getting 100K rows of sample data from 1. JSON and 2. MySQL, into an identical target array, to illustrate relative performance for saturating an array with large datasets from various common data sources.

Answer (score 1):

If it was a suspicious bottleneck (perhaps millions of items?) I would go straight to do a little performance test. See this little script, comparing multiple key updates once `array[key = , , ]` and multiple separate key updates in consecutive  statements `array[key] =` when opdating 1.000.000 times :

```php
$time_start = microtime(true);
$a1 = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; ++$i) {
  $a1 = [
    'key1' => $i, 
    'key2' => $i + 1
  ];
}
$time_end = microtime(true);
printf('Took %f seconds for inline array[key = ]<br>', $time_end - $time_start);
 
$time_start = microtime(true);
$a2 = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; ++$i) {
  $a2['key1'] = $i;
  $a2['key2'] = $i + 1;
}
$time_end = microtime(true);
printf('Took %f seconds for array[key] = <br>', $time_end - $time_start);
```

That gives me (the picture is more or less the same on each run) :

```
Took 0.195255 seconds for inline array[key = ]
Took 0.204276 seconds for array[key] =
```

So, it really doesn't matter - no noticeable difference you have to worry about - but updating multiple keys in one statement seems to be a little bit faster. Most of the times, not guaranteed always.

*And that is also exactly what we could expect*! Think about it logically: Updating the array keys in one statement is slightly more efficient than updating the same array keys by multiple consecutive statements, simply because the array in memory are accessed fewer times.

Comment: So it's a fairly marginal difference when it comes to a couple of values. However, turns out that if you add 100K array members in one go, there's actually a 50% benefit (both CPU and RAM) over 1-by-1 adding. Have updated test results in my post.

Comment: Yes of course, that is implied by what I wrote. The more keys, the more statements and access to the array in RAM you spare. 100K * 0.00001 are obvious more than 2 * 0.00001. But very unlikely anyone have arrays with say 1000 keys, if they have that need, they wouldnt use arrays at all.

Comment: Yeah it would be madness to manually curate arrays of that size. There is however a use case here for big arrays, e.g. with cached data. I often put together scripts that transform datasets and store the outcome into files that are then used by other applications. (Where creating databases wouldn't be worth the trouble.) In other news, turns out JSON is still a winner (by 3x) over including "native arrays".

Comment: @MarkusAO, I agree with that. I dont know for sure, but have the feeling that the reason is that the good ol' native PHP array functions (and the implementation of the array-type itself) are not so optimized than the later implementation of JSON support (as far as I recall v5 or so). Perhaps the reason so many tends to use arrays is based on the fact, that it in long time was the most flexible datatype, and stdclasses was "so hard" back in the late 90'ties and 00'es, when PHP became the "goto-language" for anyone who wanted to do some scripting on their websites.

Comment: thank you so much @MarkusAO and davidKonrad for the great answers you put.. i really appreciated your efforts.. now i have a much better picture on what i need to do.. i wish i could accept both answers.. but i have to choose one.. thanks again